# How to change the boolean value of C to the boolean value of python on mac

Tags: python, c

I would like to code in c ,but use the value in python by compile the c source file to .so file.

Comment: If the value of boolean is the only problem you're having doing that, then you're in pretty good shape. Would you care to show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ctypes](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html) [library](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) is probably the easiest way to do this.